# fetch not firing in service worker in Firefox 64

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker

I have a GatsbyJS website and I'm trying to load data using `fetch` but for some reason, it's not firing/the Promise is not returning in Firefox.

This is my service worker code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
  console.log('Service worker installing...');
  // self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  console.log('Service worker activating...');
  // listener.waitUntil(clients.claim());
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      return json;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Failed to fetch because ', err);
    });
});
```

This is the console output in Chrome:
[image]

and the console output in Firefox:
[image]

For some reason, Firefox doesn't run `then` or `catch`. I would appreciate if someone could help me debug this problem.

Comment: just for further debug, can you put a `console.log` before the `const json = ...` line

Comment: I added `console.log('response returned');` before `const json = ...` like you asked, and it didn't print 'response returned'.

Comment: Wrap the whole fetch chain in a  try catch.

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened, one thing I did notice though is when I put the service workers page next to my website, the service workers page flickered with my local site showing up then instantly disappearing.